# What is the extension ID in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the devcontainer document at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference

It writes that "An array of extension IDs that specify the extensions that should be installed inside the container when it is created. Defaults to []". But what are extension IDs? I did not find such IDs in the web pages of extensions.

Comment: It's referred to as "unique identifier" on the pages for extensions, e.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeStream.codestream (and you can see it's also in the URL).

Comment: If you right-click on an extension or click on ⚙️ for it in VS Code, there is a "Copy Extension ID" option too

Comment: It is also in each extension's `package.json`.  In general, it is the `publisher`.`nameOfExtension` of the extension.  Publisher being who made it.

Comment: Thanks! I also found that we can export the list of all the installed extensions from "Setting Sync: show synced data" if the setting sync is on.

Answer (score 4):

You can find ID into extension description:

1. Open VisualStudioCode
2. Go to "Extensions" (by pressing Ctrl+Shift+X)
3. Select extension, which ID you would like to know
4. In Section "Details", find sub-section "More info"
5. "Identifier" field will be your ID.

[Demonstration#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9GWv.png)

Or you can go into https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers and find same ID on a page.

[Demonstration#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2yJg.png)