# How do I separate mandatory extensions and personal extensions in devcontainer

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

The `devcontainer.json` allows adding extensions to be installed in a container.

I want to be able to set the list of mandatory extensions to be used by all team members, like `rust-lang.rust-analyzer` and `llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd` and another file for personal extensions.

Ideally, the personal one would be added to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode does not support personal extenstions via `.devcontainer.json`, however they can be cofigured via settings as follows:

- Open Settings
- Paste `dev.containers.defaultExtensions` to the Search
  field
- Add [Extension ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75917670/1333734) to the list
- Rebuild container

Comment: Dev comment on GitHub confirming: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7650#issuecomment-1341149704

Answer (score -3):

To add a file for personal extensions that can be added to the container, you can create a new file, such as "my-extensions.json", and add it to the ".gitignore" file to prevent it from being committed to the repository. In the my-extensions.json file, you can add the "extensions" property with an array of the extension IDs that you want to be installed in your personal container. For example:

```
{
  "devcontainer": {
    "extensions": [
      "my-extension-id-1",
      "my-extension-id-2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but creating this file does nothing. Did you make this up?